# Button Click listeners for buttons inside Grid Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a Grid Layout which has as many as 9 buttons in it. I want to set button click listeners for each button.

This is what I have done so far which obviously isn't working:

**Fragment File**:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
int choice = -1;
Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout,container,false);

    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    btn3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b3);
    btn4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b4);
    btn5 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b5);
    btn6 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b6);
    btn7 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b7);
    btn8 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b8);
    btn9 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b9);
    if(choice == 0)
        ButtonClicked1();
    else
    if(choice == 1)
        ButtonClicked2();
    choice = getArguments().getInt("ch");
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(choice), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return view;
}

public void ButtonClicked1(){
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void ButtonClicked2() {
}
```

}

**Its XML file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/RL">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:columnWidth="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Your choice variable is initialized with -1, so 'ButtonClicked1()' is never called. Move the line 'choice = getArguments().getInt("ch");' up and be sure to set ch in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got object of View class or its subclasses you can register `OnClickListener` for it so

```
btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
...
btn9 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b9);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

and so on. If you would like to controll it by passing extra arguments you have to read them first:

```
choice = getArguments().getInt("ch");
if(choice == 0){
    ButtonClicked1();
} else if(choice == 1){
    ButtonClicked2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, well, `choice` is `-1`, and so neither `ButtonClicked1()` nor `ButtonClicked2()` are going to be called.

You are not calling `choice = getArguments().getInt("ch");` until *after* you check `choice` to see if it is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

instead this:

```
if(choice == 0) // at this point choice=-1
        ButtonClicked1();
    else
    if(choice == 1) //at this point choice=-1
        ButtonClicked2();
    choice = getArguments().getInt("ch"); // now you are getting value
```

do this:

```
choice = getArguments().getInt("ch"); // now you are getting value
if(choice == 0) // at this point choice="ch value"
            ButtonClicked1();
        else
        if(choice == 1) //at this point choice="ch value"
            ButtonClicked2();
```